# How can i remove blank area caused by theme's post meta boxes?

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have a problem with my theme's post screen metaboxes.
When i add new portfolio items, there is some meta boxes which i dont need to use in my post screen. And if i leave them blank and publish the post,
it leaves a blank area on the top of my page. And anything i place with visual composer stayes under of this blank area.

How can i remove these empty area caused by these meta boxes?

Thanks for your time..

[image: Theme's meta boxes in my add portfolio post page]

[image: Blank area in my posts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is few steps:

1. Right click on your area what you want to change/remove and inspect in console.
2. Find in console HTML part what you want change/remove
3. Look if have some ID or unique class.
4. If you find some unique ID or class, just simple add custom CSS in your template with property `display:none !important;`
5. If you not find any kind of unique ID or class, try to find some parent ID or class and find in CSS right route to your element you want remove/change and add CSS property to it.

The worst thing you can do also is to go inside PHP and find that element and remove inside template or plugin.

Comment: i've inspected elements and find it in on posttype.php and deleted wole line fixed my issue thanks!